# Close SSH Session after 3 sec

Tags: go, ssh

I have a for loop which will connect to a server via SSH, kill some processes. The issue that I am running into is that my program tries to reconnect to the server after killing all processes (including SSH) which won't work. The program crashes.

How can I close the ssh connection after 3 seconds and move on with the for loop?

```
 for i := 0; i < 900; i++ {
    // pick random number
    randomServer := fmt.Sprint(serverList[rand.Intn(len(serverList))])

    // print info
    logrus.Warn("Loop: ", i)
    logrus.Warn("Connecting to: ", randomServer)

    // connect to server
    cli := ssh.NewSSHClient("root", randomServer)

    // execute any command
    cli.ExecuteCmd("killall5")
    cli.ExecuteCmd("exit")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what ssh lib are you using but based on your code it can be [this](https://github.com/coreos/fleet/blob/master/ssh/ssh.go#L207)

To avoid program crash you need to check if ssh connection was established successfully. To do this check error produced by ssh.NewSSHClient

```
for i := 0; i < 900; i++ {
    // pick random number
    randomServer := fmt.Sprint(serverList[rand.Intn(len(serverList))])

    // print info
    logrus.Warn("Loop: ", i)
    logrus.Warn("Connecting to: ", randomServer)

    // connect to server
    cli, err := ssh.NewSSHClient("root", randomServer)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        continue;
    }

    // execute any command
    cli.ExecuteCmd("killall5")
    cli.ExecuteCmd("exit")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit missing from the code you posted.. Like which packages are being used etc.. however as an example I've provide code that uses the context package to add a 3 second timeout. You can modify this as you see fit, but I think the use of context is very appropriate here.  If you've never used them see the standard library docs [here](https://golang.org/pkg/context/) and do some googling for more examples.

```
// whatever this is
var serverList []string

func serverStuff(ctx context.Context, loop int, server string) {
    // print info
    logrus.Warn("Loop: ", loop)
    logrus.Warn("Connecting to: ", server)

    // connect to server
    cli := ssh.NewSSHClient("root", server)
    // execute any command
    cli.ExecuteCmd("killall5")
    return
}

func main() {

    for i := 0; i < 900; i++ {
        // pick random number
        // create a context that waits 3 seconds
        ctx := context.Background()
        ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, 3*time.Second)
        defer cancel()

        randomServer := fmt.Sprint(serverList[rand.Intn(len(serverList))])
        go serverStuff(ctx, i, randomServer)
        for {
            select {
            case <-ctx.Done(): // 3 seconds have passed break this loop bring us back to the top
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```